# Dompdf float does not float

Tags: php, css, css-float, dompdf

I'm using the latest version of Dompdf and per documentation the float property is enabled by default but the float does not works.
Instead the elements are overflowing from container.

I have the following Dompdf setup

```
  $downloadName = $fileName != '' ? $fileName . '.pdf' : 'download.pdf';

    $dompdf = new Dompdf([
        'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true,
        'defaultPaperSize' => 'a4',
        'dpi' => 72,
        'enableCssFloat' => true,
        'isPhpEnabled' => true,
        'debugCss' => true,
        'debugLayout' => true,
        'debugLayoutLines' => true,
        'isRemoteEnabled' => true
      ]);


    $dompdf->loadHtml($html);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    // Render the HTML as PDF
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($downloadName);
```

Produced result[image]

Rendered in Browser:

[image]

HTML + CSS behind

```css
    @page {
        size: a4 portrait;
      }
      html {
        width: 100%;
      }
      
      body {
        width: 100%;
      }
      body a {
        display: none;
      }
      body img {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
      }
      body .test {
        height: 100%;
      }
      body .test__inner {
        display: none;
      }
      body .test__productswrapper {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
      }
      body .test__products {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
        padding: 0;
        width: 560px;
      }
      body .test__productstrigger {
        display: block;
        width: 40%;
        background-color: yellow;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                box-sizing: border-box;
        min-height: 200px;
        height: 300px;
        max-height: 300px;
        float: left;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
      body .test .box_productcard {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      body .test .box_productcard img {
        display: none;
      }
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="test__inner">
        <h1 class="test__title">Test</h1>

        <div class="test__contact">
          <div class="test__address">
            Test
            <br />lorep ipsum <br />lorep ipsum
            <br />lorep ipsum
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="test__productscontainer">
    <div class="test__productlist">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="test__productswrapper">
            <ul class="test__products">
              <li class="test__productstrigger">
                <a href="/link_product" class="test__productslink">
                  <div class="box_productcard">
                    <div class="box_productcard__cover">
                      <img src="/cover-image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>

                    <h3 class="box_productcard__title">Product Title</h3>

                    <div class="box_productcard__company">Company</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="test__productstrigger">
                <a href="/link_product" class="test__productslink">
                  <div class="box_productcard">
                    <div class="box_productcard__cover">
                      <img src="/cover-image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>

                    <h3 class="box_productcard__title">Product Title</h3>

                    <div class="box_productcard__company">Company</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="test__productstrigger">
                <a href="/link_product" class="test__productslink">
                  <div class="box_productcard">
                    <div class="box_productcard__cover">
                      <img src="/cover-image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>

                    <h3 class="box_productcard__title">Product Title</h3>

                    <div class="box_productcard__company">Company</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="test__productstrigger">
                <a href="/link_product" class="test__productslink">
                  <div class="box_productcard">
                    <div class="box_productcard__cover">
                      <img src="/cover-image.jpg" alt="" title="" />
                    </div>

                    <h3 class="box_productcard__title">Product Title</h3>

                    <div class="box_productcard__company">Company</div>
                  </div>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1. render your html in a browser to see if it works there, if it does it is a domPDF issue.
2. try the css overflow property
3. share your html

Comment: I have played around with this for a bit, and it looks like your best bet is to do two things: 1. use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left`
2. make sure the total width of all your elements does not exceed the width of A4 (210mm)

Alternatively you could switch to a different library for generating pdf from html.